# Rails form that requires multiple parameters from different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently practicing how to make a pedigree system, I have successfully implemented users who own dogs, but I want those users to be able to create a pedigree relationship to other dog's profiles like in pic related:
[My view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nfb5.jpg)

My issue is that when I click the Submit button to create the relationship (or at least know if it works) I get a "The action 'new' could not be found for PedigreeController" error message. Here is my controller and as you can see I only have a create and a destroy method. I tried changing the url in the view to create but without luck. I have also added resources :pedigree to my route file.

```
 class PedigreeController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @dog = Dog.find(params[:dog_id])
    #@pedigree = pedigrees.build(dog_id: @dog.id, relative_id: @dog.id, relation_name: :string)
    @pedigree = @dog.build_pedigree(pedigree_params)
    if @pedigree.save
      flash[:success] = "Dog relative added."
      redirect_to access_dogmenu_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Unable to add this dog as relative"
      redirect_to access_dogmenu_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pedigree = @dog.pedigrees.find(params[:id])
    @pedigree.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Relative removed."
    redirect_to access_dogmenu_path
  end

  private

  def pedigree_params
    params.require(:pedigree).permit(:dog_id, :relative_id, :relation_name)
  end
end
```

I have made a pedigree.rb model which is used to create the dogs relationships.

```
class Pedigree < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
  belongs_to :relative, class_name: Dog
end
```

This is the dog.rb model

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pedigrees
  has_many :relatives, through: :pedigrees, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Here is what I have currently in my view (which shows in every dog profile):

```
...
<h3>Relatives: </h3>
  <ul>
   <% for pedigree in @dog.pedigrees %>
     <li>
     <%= pedigree.relative.dname %>'s - <%= pedigree.relative.relation_name %>
                     <%= link_to "Remove", pedigree, method: :delete %>
      </li>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
<h4>Add this dog as your dog's relative: </h4>
  <%= form_for(Pedigree.new, url: new_pedigree_path) do |p| %>
  Select your dog:
  <%= p.collection_select(:dog_id, @dogs,:id, :dname, :prompt => "Select your dog") %><br>
  Select your dog relation to the dog from this profile:
  <%= select_tag(:relation_id, options_for_select([['Sibling', 1], ['Parent', 2], ['Grandparent', 3], ['Great-grandparent', 4], ['Child', 5], ['Grandchild', 6], ['Great-grandchild', 7]])) %><br>
 <%= p.submit 'Add Relation' %>
 <% end %>
...
```

To create a pedigree relation 3 things are needed:

1. The dog_id of the current user's dog of choice (The collection_select seems to be working).
2. The relative_id of the dog that will become a relative, in this case the relative_id should be taken straight from the show page for example http://localhost:3000/dogs/2 would be sending dog_id=2 into the form. **Does anybody know how would I go about including this in my form?**
3. the relation_name like sibling, parent, etc. The drop down selector seems to be working ok.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An html form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/some/url">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Add Relation" />
</form>
```

And when you click on the Submit button, a request is sent to the url specified in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag.

You set the action attribute to:

```
url: new_pedigree_path
```

And, when you create the route:

```
resources :pedigree
```

you get the following path helpers:

```
photos_path returns /photos
new_photo_path returns /photos/new
edit_photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance, edit_photo_path(10) returns /photos/10/edit)
photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

So, the url you set for the action attribute is: `/pedigree/new`, which tries to hit the `new()` action in the `PedigreeController`.

By default, form_for() creates a form with the action attribute set to `/pedigree`.  See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

And, your `resources route` gets you the following url-to-action mappings:

[image]
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

If you check the chart for `/pedigree` when part of a `post` request--which is the type of request that form_for() sends(see the resulting html at the link above again)--the request will route to the `create()` action in the PedigreeController.

> The relative_id of the dog that will become a relative,...  Does
>   anybody know how would I go about including this in my form?

1. When you create the form, you can create a `hidden form field` and set its value to the relative_id.  Then when the user submits the form, the name/value pair will be in the `params` hash.
2. In the action that sends the form back, you can add the relative_id to the `sessions` hash, then look it up again when the user submits the form.
3. In the action that sends the form back, you can set a `cookie` in the response: `cookies[:name] = value`. Then when the user submits the form, the cookie will be sent back to you in the headers of the request, and you can retrieve the value from the `cookies` hash.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what routes are made and a way in that I can include the dog_id in my post request.